# Laravel API Auth with Passport and React

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel 5.5 Application that's using the session based auth out of the box. On some of these pages I have react components that need to get/post data from/to an API.

What is the best practice for handling this? Do I simply hide the API endpoints behind the auth? This would work but should I be using Laravel Passport for this instead?

I've had a play with Passport and it seems that this would work but I don't need users to be able to create clients and grant 3rd party applications permission etc. There is just the first party react app consuming the data from inside the laravel application (view).

From my initial experimenting with it, it seems I'd need to have the login call made first to receive an access token to then make further calls. As the user will already be authenticated in the session is there an easier way?

I'm not sure if Passport is intended to be used for this purpose or not. I'd rather take the time to get it right now as I'd like to get the foundations right now if the app scales.

Answer (score 2):

You can proxy authentication with Passport. Using the password grant type users would still log in with their username/password, then behind the scenes make an internal request to Passport to obtain an access token.

Restrict what routes are available when registering in a service provider by passing in:

```
Passport::routes(function ($router) {
    $router->forAccessTokens();
    $router->forTransientTokens();
});
```

That limits access to personal tokens and refresh tokens only. A client will be created when you run `php artisan passport:install`.

Setup a middleware to merge the password grant client id and secret in with the request, then make a call to the authorization endpoint. Then it's just a matter of returning the encrypted token and observing the Authorization header for requests to your api.